# How to compute an IIR Filter frequency response in Octave/MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filtering, octave

I'm trying to compute the frequency response of an IIR filter.

The transfer function of the filter is:

[image]

The value of `a` is computed as:

```
f     = 1000;
fsamp = 16000;
a     = 1 / (1 + (2 * pi * f) / fsamp);
```

Ok so now I have the transfer function of my IIR filter. How should I now compute the frequency response? I thought about using the `freqz` function, but I need help defining the arguments, how do i define the numerator and denominator polynomials?

Comment: This site does not support LaTex. The numerator and denominator for `freqz` are those from your H(z), expressed as polynomials of the variable z^-1. Have you seen [this example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqz.html#bt829u7)?

Comment: Yes I've tried to follow that example but wasn't able to, mainly because since I only have one polynomial in the numerator and denominator, how should I use the conv function?

Comment: No need for `conv` here. `conv` is polynomial multiplication, which is used in the example because the num and den are both products of polynomials. In your case the "`b`" for `freqz` would be `1-a`  (where `a` is your variable) and the "`a`" for `freqz` would be `[1,-a]`. See if the result of that makes sense

Comment: Thank you! So using what you said defining num=[1-a] and den=[1, -a], I then do freqz(num, den, 'whole', 2001); just like the example but get this error in Octave:
error: plot: no data to plot
error: called from
    __plt__ at line 127 column 11
    plot at line 229 column 10
    freqz_plot at line 60 column 3
    freqz at line 199 column 5

Comment: Not sure what `'whole'` does. `freqz(num, den, 2001)` works in my Octave version

Answer (score 3):

```
f=1000; fsamp=16000; a=1/(1+(2*pi*f)/fsamp);
a = [1 -a];
b = [(1-a) 0];
w = logspace(-1,1);

h = freqs(b,a,w);
mag = abs(h);
phase = angle(h);
phasedeg = phase*180/pi;

subplot(2,1,1)
loglog(w,mag)
grid on
xlabel('Frequency (rad/s)')
ylabel('Magnitude')

subplot(2,1,2)
semilogx(w,phasedeg)
grid on
xlabel('Frequency (rad/s)')
ylabel('Phase (degrees)')
```

This is based on this solution https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/freqs.html by Mathworks. And I get this outcome:

[image]

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much! However you seem to be getting a highpass filter when the filter is supposed to be lowpass... Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Oh and I tried to run that and it didn't work in Octave :(

Comment: @GrangerObliviate Elina's code works on octave too. You just need to load the `signal` package first (i.e. `pkg load signal`). Obviously if you don't have the package installed you'll need to install it first (e.g. `pkg install -forge signal`)

Comment: My code is for Matlab that's why, maybe there are some differences there also. Maybe the numerator or the denumerator must be changed in order to get the filter that you want.

Comment: I don't think `freqs` is the right tool for two reasons: (1) `freqs` uses `s` as variable, whereas `freqz` (as in my answer) uses `z^-1`. That's why applying `freqs` directly to the coefficients in the question doesn't give a correct result. (2) `freqs` is for analog filters (with frequency in Hz), not for discrete-time filters cc @GrangerObliviate

Comment: @Elina_syr Sorry that I had to downvote. Let me know if you fix the answer so I can remove my downvote

Answer (score 1):

The first two inputs of `freqz` are respectively the numerator and denominator of the transfer function expressed as polynomials of the variable *z*<sup>−1</sup>:

```
a = 0.7; % example value
num = 1-a;
den = [1, -a];
freqz(num, den, 1001)
```

[image]